# Run arbitrary HTML5 using Puppeteer as securely as possible?

Tags: puppeteer, websecurity

I have a use case, where I need to run arbitrary HTML5 code (HTML, CSS, JS, WASM) supplied by end users and take a screenshot of the rendered website. I'd like to use [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) to do this. I am aware that it's generally unsafe to run arbitrary code provided by end users on your server, but need to do this for this use case. How do I do this in the most secure way possible?

Comment: I think you just need to build and your end user code in a separated port like `http://localhost:8080/` and let puppeteer go to this url then take a screenshot.